# How do I drain this gutter away from the house?

Tags: drain, gutters

In the picture below B is 2-3 inces below C
A is 2-3 inces below C
Currently the downspout goes to the main drain of the house
I would like to drain the gutter on my lawn near point A

What is the best option (esthetically and techically)?

[image]

Comment: You could turn it a few feet up from point B, and run it at a slope against the foundation wall and into that planter. From there you could just let it dump, or route another drain through the planter and out the front.

Comment: Isn't it normally not allowed to drain gutters into a house drain?

Comment: @Rob The house was built that way. The city is now asking us to disconnect.  Jacob Edmond:  It is out of question to drain into the planter.

Comment: @Jacob Edmond stated your best plan aesthetically and functionally IMO; water does not run uphill. If it is "out of the question to drain into the planter", then, as he said, route the drain *through* the planter rather than into the planter.

Comment: I think that I need to go the route I marked on the picture because there are an electrical box and a TV cable box attached to the wall to the left of the gutter. I am thinking about using PVC drain pipe and a pop out at point A,

Comment: OK, just so you know that from "B" to "C", and up the downspout to the height of "C" you will have standing water. Or alternatively, since these are generally not water-tight, that standing water will drain next to the house where you said you did not want it.

Comment: If I use a pop up that means the PVC pipe will be buried under ground and properly sloped